# Probability density function (PDF) problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, independence, density-function

#### Problem

$X$ and $Y$ random variables, the common probability density function of $X$ and $Y$ is given as follows:
$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
ke^{-x-y},&\textrm{when  } x\geqslant y\geqslant 0\\
0\;,&\textrm{otherwise  }
\end{cases}
$$

a) Find the constant $k$

---

### Proposed Solution

$$\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\int_{x=0}^{\infty} ke^{-x-y} dxdy = 1$$

---

Is any of my work correct? Any feedback is much appreciated, and if you think I should add more details to my calculations, please point it out and I will edit my work accordingly.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is the support of the joint distribution $ 0 \leq y \leq x$? In such case $(X, Y)$ cannot be independent as the support is not rectangular. Also then the integration limit in part a) is incorrect.

Comment: @BGM Im totally agreed with you, they can't be independent because the condition not occurred, in part a) if the limit is incorrect what it should be then?

Comment: The equation is $ \int_0^{\infty} \int_y^{\infty} k\cdot e^{-x-y} \, dx \, dy=1$

Comment: @callculus if so, how it could be solved bro? could you help please or the result will be the same equal to 1, if so please clarify the steps it will be much appreciated.

Comment: You firstly solve the inner integral $\int_y^{\infty} k\cdot e^{-x-y} \, dx $. Btw, the constant k and $e^{-y}$ can be factored out.

Comment: @callculus Could you provide a complete answer at least for part a), it will be appreciated.

Comment: Please try to avoid making trivial edits to your question.

Comment: @MohammedLubbad What´s up?

Comment: @callculus what is the final result of  k then?

Comment: @MohammedLubbad $\frac{k}2=1$. Multiplying the equation by 2 gives $k=2$

Comment: @MohammedLubbad When I answer a question I'm waiting a while till I get a reply. But I cannot wait several hours.

Comment: @callculus Thanks a lot, Im sorry for this delay, Could you confirm if the other parts are correct or not also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) $\int_0^{\infty} \int_y^{\infty} k\cdot e^{-x-y} \, dx \, dy$

inner integral: $\int_y^{\infty} k\cdot e^{-x-y} \, dx=k\cdot e^{-y}\int_y^{\infty} e^{-x} \, dx$

$$=k\cdot e^{-y}\cdot \left(-e^{-x}\bigg|_y^{\infty}\right)=k\cdot e^{-y}\cdot(-0-(-e^{-y}))=k\cdot e^{-2y}$$

Now the outer integral: $\int_0^{\infty} k\cdot e^{-2y} \, dy=k\cdot \int_0^{\infty} e^{-2y} \, dy$

$$=k\cdot  \left(-\frac12 \cdot e^{-2y}\bigg|_0^{\infty}\right)=k\cdot(-0-(-\frac12))=\frac{k}2=1$$

$\Rightarrow k=...$

Comment: I need the other parts also please

Comment: @MohammedLubbad I think you have posted the other part [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3713480/find-the-marginal-probability-function-of-x-and-y), right? It´s all ok now?

Answer (score 1):

[Reprising this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3713480/find-the-marginal-probability-function-of-x-and-y)

After understanding that $k=2$, your joint density is the following

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=2e^{-x}e^{-y}\mathbb{1}_{[0;+\infty)}(x)\mathbb{1}_{[0;x]}(y)$$

or equivalently

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=2e^{-x}e^{-y}\mathbb{1}_{[0;+\infty)}(y)\mathbb{1}_{[y;+\infty)}(x)$$

now to get the marginals  you have only to integrate the opposite variable "copying" the integral extremes in the $f(x,y)$ formula

Thus

$$f_X(x)=\int_0^x [2e^{-x}e^{-y} ]dy=2e^{-x}(1-e^{-x})\mathbb{1}_{[0;+\infty)}(x)$$

$$f_y(y)=\int_y^{+\infty} [2e^{-x}e^{-y} ]dx=2e^{-2y}\mathbb{1}_{[0;+\infty)}(y)$$

$Y\sim Exp(2)$