# Find the marginal probability function of X and Y

Tags: probability, marginal-probability

#### Problem

$X$ and $Y$ random variables, the common probability density function of $X$ and $Y$ is given as follows:
$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
2e^{-x-y},&\textrm{when  } x\geqslant y\geqslant 0\\
0\;,&\textrm{otherwise  }
\end{cases}
$$

Find the marginal probability function for $X$ and $Y$

---

### Proposed Solution

$$ h(x) = \int_{y}^{\infty}f_{(x,y)} dy = \int_{y}^{\infty} 2e^{-x-y} dy = e^{-x} = \frac{2}{e^x}$$

$$ g(y) = \int_{0}^{\infty}f_{(x,y)} dy = \frac{2}{e^y} $$

### $$ h(x) = \frac{2}{e^x} , g(y) = \frac{2}{e^y}$$

Is any of my work correct? Any feedback is much appreciated, and if you think I should add more details to my calculations, please point it out and I will edit my work accordingly.

Thank you for your time.

---

Update:
I made a change according to k = 2

Comment: Do not [repost](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3708363/321264) your questions please. What was the point of removing the other parts from the last question?

Comment: @StubbornAtom According to you best practices "make it simple & easy to solve" I changes the way of my question by dividing it to small pieces each part into separated question. Thats why

Answer (score 1):

No, the work you have above is not correct.  Close, but still wrong.

The support for the joint probability density function is $\{\langle x,y\rangle: 0\leq y\leq x\}$.  Therefore, *what* are the **domains** of integration for the marginal probability density functions?

---

PS: The [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3708363/probability-density-function-pdf-problem) to your previous question told you to find $k$ by using $\int_0^\infty\int_{\color{blue}y}^\infty k\mathrm e^{-x-y}~\mathrm d y~\mathrm d x=1$ so … think about this a little more.